# After AJAX call, data is null

Tags: php, jquery

When I make an AJAX call from a form, it shows it is successful, but the data object is null. The code is as follows:

```
$.ajax(
  {
    url: 'shipprocess.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data)
      {
    alert('Data is: ' + data);
    alert('The AJAX request was a success.');
      },
    'error': function()
      {
    alert('An unexpected error occurred.');
      }
  });
return false;
```

The form looks like this:

```
<div class="processedDate">
<form action="shipprocess.php" method="POST" id="shipProcess2" name="shipProcess2">
<input type="hidden" name="empID" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="thisOrderID" id="thisOrderID2" value="2" />
<label>Date Shipped </label>
<input type="text"  name="shipDate" id="shipDate2" class="shipDate" size="20" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="shipped" id="shipped2" class="shipped" value="Shipped!" />
</form>
</div>
```

After the AJAX call is made, Firebug shows the status as 200 and content length as 0. The script that processes the form is called shipprocess.php. It echos the following data when the return: false; line is commented out:

```
[ { "sd": "2012-09-17", "eid": "1", "oid": "2", "efn": "Johnathan", "eln": "Smith" } ]
```

For some reason, the script keeps alerting that data is null. A complete example can be found at http://www.yellowcas.com/ship/shipexample.php. This example shows the alert message that the data object is null when you submit the form. I also have a complete example of the data that the shipprocess.php script returns at http://www.yellowcas.com/ship/shipexample1.php. I have used AJAX before to populate the city and state input fields for a zip code that is entered by the user. The jQuery script is almost identical except for the fact that I use GET instead of POST for the zip code form.

I have tried declaring the header in PHP as JSON data, but that doesn't help either. Firebug doesn't seem to be giving me any helpful information either. I have tested the script using a different file called testjson.html. In that file, I put valid JSON data as the only line in the file with no headers at all, and it returns the data variable as an object. That example is at www.yellowcas.com/ship/shipexample2.php. I couldn't post more than 2 hyperlinks. If you would like to see the code for shipprocess.php, I will gladly post it. I just don't want to make this post too long. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I decided to post the shipprocess.php code to be sure you can see what I have done.It is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once('dblogin.php');
require_once('dbconnect.php');
require_once('funcs.php');
$err = array();
$datePattern = "!^(\\d\\d)[-/](\\d\\d)[-/](\\d\\d(?:\\d\\d)?)$!";
$psErr = "Shipping date is required.";
$emErr = "Employee ID is missing.";
$orErr = "Order ID is missing.";
if(isset($_POST['shipped']))
  {
    $postEID = clean($_POST['empID'],$emErr,$n);
    $postOID = clean($_POST['thisOrderID'],$orErr,$n);
    $postShipDate = clean($_POST['shipDate'],$psErr,$n);
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    if($postEID == $emErr)
      {
    $err[] = $postEID;
      }
    else
      {
    $query = "SELECT FK_UserID,FirstName,LastName FROM employees WHERE EmployeeID = '$postEID'";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) < 1)
      {
        $err[] = "Employee does not exist.";
      }
    else
      {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
          {
        $retUserID = $row['FK_UserID'];
        $retFirstName = $row['FirstName'];
        $retLastName = $row['LastName'];
          }
      }
      }
    if($postOID == $orErr)
      {
    $err[] = $postOID;
      }
    if($postShipDate == $psErr)
      {
    $err[] = $postShipDate;
      }
    else
      {
    if (preg_match($datePattern,$postShipDate,$sMatches))
      {
        $sMonth = $sMatches[1];
        $sDay = $sMatches[2];
        $sYear = $sMatches[3];
        if(checkdate($sMonth,$sDay,$sYear))
          {
        $shipDate = "$sYear-$sMonth-$sDay";
          }
        else
          {
        $err[] = "Invalid shipping date.";
          }
      }
    else
      {
        $err[] = "Invalid Shipping Date";
      }
      }
    if(empty($err))
    //  Keep processing the information if there are no errors.
      {
    $data[] = "$postEID,$shipDate,$postOID,$now,$retFirstName,$retLastName";
      }
    else
    //  Return the errors to the user so corrections can be made.
      {
        $data[] = implode(",",$err);
      }
    for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($data);$i++)
      {
    $info = explode(",",$data[$i]);
    $data[$i] = $info;
      }
    $result = array();
    for ($y=0;$y<sizeof($data);$y++)
      {
    if (($data[$y][0]) !== false)
      {
        array_push($result, array("sd"=>$data[$y][1], "eid"=>$data[$y][0], "oid" => $data[$y][2], "efn"=>$data[$y][4], "eln"=>$data[$y][5]));
      }
    if (count($result) > 2)
      {
        break;
      }
      }
  }
echo array_to_json($result);
?>
```

Please try out the three example pages I have provided to see what the different results are. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code lacks at least 2 things:

1: When posting with Ajax, you have to send post data. So you have to tell what data you want to send. Most of the time it will be the *serialized form* data, but it could be anything.

```
var dataString = 'name=Gr G';
$.ajax(
  {
    url: 'shipprocess.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: dataString,
    type: 'POST',
    ...
```

2: You expect a return value, but you do not send a return value. In `shipprocess.php` after processing you should echo somethning like this:

```
...    
echo 'data received and processed';
...
```

Comment: In shipprocess.php, I do echo the return value I want. If you checkout the shipexample1.php link above, you will see that it returns JSON data.The shipprocess.php script is:

Comment: I have posted the shipprocess.php code for review. Please try out all three complete examples I provided. They all give different results. Thank you.

Comment: You should do your own debugging, I am not here to code for you!

Comment: I didn't mean to offend you. I'm sorry if I did. I'm just  frustrated with this code because i have spent the last 2 days working on this with no results. It feels like I'm banging my head against a brick wall. I do appreciate your quick response. Thank you.

Comment: Fix point 1 and do a var_dump($_POST); die; in the first line of shipprocess.php and see what is happening

Comment: It appears that all the POST data is being transmitted. I put this line after dataType: data: $('#shipProcess2').serialize(),  Then I put var_dump($_POST) in shipprocess.php and got the following: array(4) { ["empID"]=> string(1) "1" ["thisOrderID"]=> string(1) "2" ["shipDate"]=> string(10) "09/17/2012" ["shipped"]=> string(8) "Shipped!" } I may try changing it to a get request and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I think I figured it out. When I serialize the data, it does not add the "shipped" parameter to the data. In line 10 of shipprocess.php, this is the line that is stopping it from processing the data: `if(isset($_POST['shipped']))`  Since the "shipped" parameter is not passed, the script is not processing anything. Thank you for bearing with me. I do appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Gladly. I accepted the answer, but it won't let me vote it up because I don't have 15 reputation yet. I really appreciate you answering my post. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the $.ajax() method, you have to specify the "data" parameter with the contents of your form.

So you should do something like :

```
$.ajax({
    "url": 'shipprocess.php',
    "dataType": 'json',
    "type": 'POST',
    "data": $("#myform").serialize(),
});
```

Comment: I tried doing this. The data is still coming up null. An object is not being returned. You can refer to yellowcas.com/ship/shipexample3.php for the complete working example with changes.

Comment: In Firebug, it now shows the POST parameters. It still is not giving a response though.

Comment: passing data parameter is not the question

Comment: Serializing the data helped me pinpoint the problem. For some reason, it would not serialize the "shipped" parameter. I did find a way to work around it though. I just had to take out the `if(isset($_GET['shipped']))` part of the code in the shipprocess.php file, and everything went great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to send the data.

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: your url,
data: { var name: 'data here'},
dataType: 'json'
});

jqXHR.done(function (your returned data) { your stuff )};
```